# Add long polling to Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a worker environment set up to run six cron jobs.

When checking Cloudwatch I noticed that i'm receiving `57K emptyReceives/day`.

I researched about this and found `Long polling` can be used to counter this high number of `emptyReceives`.

So, I tried to reduce this by setting `Receive Message Wait Time` to `20s`  in the SQS console for the SQS queue of the worker environment.

But still I'm getting `57K emptyReceives/day`.

I checked sample for `5 minutes` and i'm getting `200 emptyReceives`.

This means `a request every 1.5 seconds`, right ?. So the setting is not working obviously.

So is there any other setting i need to set before i can use long polling with Worker environment queue?

When checked the tutorial, it says short polling occurs when:

- The `ReceiveMessage` call sets `WaitTimeSeconds` to 0.
- The `ReceiveMessage` call doesn’t set `WaitTimeSeconds`, but the queue attribute `ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds` is set to 0.

From what i understood, the `WaitTimeSeconds` of `ReceiveMessage` call must be 0 for this to happen in my case.

Is there any option i can change this ?